# Multiple nodejs servers or single?

Tags: node.js, sockets, server

For passed year I've started around 40 independent web apps using nodejs (each is running it's own server with custom port using express + socket.io). What really buggs me is that pm2 processes list have a vertical scroll )))

The question is: is it normal running so much node servers or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issues running multiple node servers, in fact when it comes to micro services architecture the more you break down, the better. There are a lot of pros and cons to this and you need to figure out if the cons affect you system more than you're willing to sacrifice. I assume when you started out you had no idea of following the micro services architecture but since your application is now distributed over 40+ services the following is an article might give you some insight into managing it properly.

https://derickbailey.com/2016/12/12/making-the-quantum-leap-from-node-js-to-microservices/

Answer (score 0):

You can start several express and socket.io instances in one NodeJS process, if you wish, like this (based on Express Hello world example):

```
const express = require('express');

// First app
const app1 = express();

app1.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app1.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app1 listening on port 3000!');
});

// Second app
const app2 = express();

app2.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World 2!');
});

app2.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log('Example app2 listening on port 3001!');
});
```

But there are several aspects to consider:

1. *Performance* - if each app is handled by a separate NodeJS process, then apparently each of them have more CPU time and high load on one of them will not affect others.
2. *Logging* - if several apps are handled by one NodeJS process you will need to distinguish which of them outputs somehow. Otherwise output will be chaotic.
3. *Аault tolerance* - if one NodeJS process handles several apps, then in case of a critical failure in one app all of them will crush simultaneously.
4. *Security* - probably some security issues in one app could affect other apps handled by one NodeJS process.

Answer (score 0):

If they all are independent then you have to create individual    server. But if they are talking to each other (I think they are talking to each other by socket.io) then you can use RPC call. Their is some lib like grpc(Google) and tchannel(Uber). I hope they can solve your problem.